# Lovasz function equality - combinatoric graph theory.

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Hello everyone,

I was wondering how to prove the following equality:

$\theta(G+H)=\theta(G)+\theta(H)$

where $G$ and $H$ are graphs and $\theta$ is the Lovasz Theta function.

correction:
I apologize for not explaining what $G+H$ denotes.

The (disjoint) union of two graphs $G$ and H, denoted $G + H$, is the graph whose vertex set is
the disjoint union of the vertex sets of $G$ and of $H$ and whose edge set is the (disjoint) union of the edge sets of $G$ and $H$

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us what $G+H$ denotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: The proof of the claim can also be found in section 18 of ["The Sandwich Theorem"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9312214) by Knuth. I feel like there is a misunderstanding in terms of definitions going on here... The OP should clarify if he or she cares about the Shannon capacity or Lovasz theta. (Also why the downvotes? :P)

---

Let $n,m$ be the number of vertices of $G$ and $K$, respectively. By definition $\theta(G+K)$ is the smallest $\theta$ so that there is an orthonormal representation of $G+K$, $\{u_1, \dots,u_n, v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ and a unit vector $c\in \mathbb R^{n+m}$ so that $(c\cdot u_i)^2\geq \frac{1}{\theta}$ and similarly $(c\cdot v_j)^2\geq \frac{1}{\theta}$. Since $u_i\cdot v_j=0$ for all $i,j$, the optimal $\theta$ is achieved when the coordinates of $c$ are so that $(c\cdot u_i)^2=\frac{r}{\theta(G)}$ and $(c\cdot v_j)^2=\frac{1-r}{\theta(K)}$ for some $0\le r\le 1$. So we obtain 
$$\theta(G+K)=\min_{0\le r\le 1} \max\left(\frac{\theta(G)}{r},\frac{\theta(K)}{1-r}\right)$$
It is not hard to see that this implies $\theta(G+K)=\theta(G)+\theta(K)$.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, Noga Alon proved in 1998 that it is *false* in general that $\theta(G+K)=\theta(G)
+\theta(K)$. See http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/shann3.pdf. See also Miniature 29 of J. Matoušek, *Thirty-three Miniatures*, American Mathematical Society, 2010.

Comment: Here's a Google Books link to Matoušek's proof on (top of) p. 141: http://books.google.com/books?id=4uF7m03l5WcC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=Miniature+29+of+J.+Matou%C5%A1ek,+Thirty-three+Miniatures&source=bl&ots=5kZdU3SmrI&sig=tclB8GdOw6c6BnaB16gRomG70pw&hl=en&ei=qD8zTrrcJofcgQfAyq2JDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: The question says "the Lov\'asz theta function". I see no reason not to take this at face value - I have never seen a lower case theta used for Shannon capacity. So I think Gjergi's solution stands.

Comment: oops, my bad. :(

Comment: Never mind, I enjoyed learning about that paper!